# Why is Chr(160) matching a '?' with certain SetLocale() values?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm seeing some weird behavior in our Classic ASP/VBScript web app, and I can't quite figure out what's going wrong. Basically, we are checking for a non-breaking space in a string (character code 160 in both Windows-1252 and Unicode). When the locale of the script is set to `3076 (zh-CN)`, the non-breaking space is matching to the question mark in the string.

Here's a short and sweet repro; since `szText` does not have a non breaking space, both message boxes should pop up with `0`.

```
dim szText
szText = "Does this match?"

' zh-CN
SetLocale(3076)
Msgbox InStr(szText, Chr(160))

' en-US
SetLocale(1033)
Msgbox InStr(szText, Chr(160))
```

Perhaps another way to ask the question is, what's the behavior of `Chr(160)` when the locale is obviously not supported by the current code page? Is switching to `ChrW(160)` (which works correctly) an appropriate fix, even if we are working with the windows-1252 code page in our responses?

Comment: The ASCII range ends at `Chr(127)`. Characters above are defined by the different ANSI codepages. [Related](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Did you try `InStr(szText, ChrW(160))`?

Comment: `Chr` has been effectively obsolete (except in very specialized and rare scenarios) for decades, Consider `ChrW` to make the locale irrelevant.

Comment: These are the two 160 chrs in chinese (simple and traditional) - х│

Comment: I should clarify that we predominantly use CodePage 1252, with some UTF8. @TomBlodget If we just swap all of our uses of `Chr` to `ChrW`, are there any side effects when using the windows-1252 encoding?

Comment: You'd have to replace each Windows-1252 code unit value with the equivalent UTF-16 code unit. There are some differences &H80-&H9F.